# Output Messagebox.show with key and value from sortedlist collection

Tags: c#

The code below is in my btnPrint click event. As you can see I have tried a few things to get the date and string list from my listbox, to a messagebox, that prints everything in my single messagebox instead of giving me a bunch of  messageboxes. It should look like:

```
4/28/2018 11:37 AM Making a question on stackoverflow
4/28/2018 3:00 PM Pulling my hair out
```

I will add where I am declaring the sorted list, below that, is what I'm using in btnPrint.

```
SortedList<DateTime, string> task = new SortedList<DateTime, string>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, string> list in task)
{
    // MessageBox.Show(" " + task.Key() + task.Value + Environment.NewLine);

    // lblScreen.Text = list.Key();
    //for (int i = 0; i < task.Count; i++)
    //{
    //   // DateTime key = task.Key;
    //   // string val = task.Value;

    //}
    MessageBox.Show(Environment.NewLine + "key: " + list.Key + " val " + list.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `MessageBox.Show` inside the `foreach`, creating an instance of `MessageBox` **for each** `KeyValuePair` you have in `task`. Instead, concatenate the string passed to the Show method and call the `MessageBox.Show` **outside** of the `foreach` loop

```
string message = string.Empty;
foreach(KeyValuePair<DateTime, string> list in task)
{
    message += "Key: " + list.Key + " Value: " + list.Value + Environment.NewLine;
}
MessageBox.Show(message);
```